# If $N$ and $M$ are normal subgroups of $G$, show that $NM/M$ is isomorphic to $N/N \cap M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

If $N$ and $M$ are normal subgroups of $G$, show that $NM/M$ is isomorphic to $N/N \cap M$ (Problem 5, I. H. Herstein, pag 87). Really I haven't idea in this problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see a "natural" map from $N$ to $NM/M$ ?Then recall first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Consider the inclusion $N \to NM$, and then the projection $NM \to NM/M$. THe kernel of this composition is $N \cap M$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note:*  I've provided the skeleton of the argument.  Try to fill in the detail of each step on your own.  If you hover your mouse over a box, it will reveal more information.

---

First construct a homomorphism $\varphi: N \to NM / M$.

> $\varphi(n) = nM$, which is in $NM / M$ because $n = n1 \in NM$.

Check that it's an epimorphism (an onto function).

> Take an arbitrary $nmM \in NM / M$.  Since $m \in M$, we have the equality of cosets $nmM = nM$, and the latter is $\varphi(n)$.

Analyze the kernel of $\varphi$.

> $$ n \in \ker \varphi \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad nM = M \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad n \in N \cap M $$

Therefore, the homomorphism $\varphi$ descends to the isomorphism $\bar\varphi: N / (N \cap M) \to nM / M$.

Answer (score 1):

Any element in $NM/M$ is of form $nmM$ where $n\in N$ and $m\in M$. Since $mM=M$, $nmM=nM$. Thus we have each element in  $NM/M$ is of form $nM$ (upto equivalence classes).

Observe that this already tells you the isomorphism since if $n\in(N\cap M)$, $nM=M$. So the distinct classes of $NM/M$ are the elements in $N$ "mod" $(N\cap M)$.

Putting it concretely, look at the map which sends $nM\rightarrow n.(N\cap M)$.